# Argument not assignable to CollectionReference error. Following AngularFire2 docs exactly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm following the documentation on AngularFire2 and getting a hard to diagnose error.  I'm trying to query a collection.

I would expect what I have to work as it's what is showing on the online docs.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface Item { name: string; }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class TestService {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item>;
  items: Observable<Item[]>;
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Item>('items', ref => {

    });
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
  addItem(item: Item) {
    this.itemsCollection.add(item);
  }
}
```

If I just do:

db.collection('Items') it works fine, its just when trying to add the query that it starts to fail on the 'Items' parameter.

Comment: Note: In the code I put here I didn't populate the query (in the collection callback (ref)), but adding that doesn't change the error.

Comment: what is the error you are getting..?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this.  I figured it out.  I was using the code straight from the docs on the first page, but typing in the next part (one line of code) to add the query.  I assumed the second parameter was a callback and so was including {} which are not in the example.

The error I was getting was "Argument of type 'Users' is not assignable of type 'CollectionReference'".  What threw me was the error on 'Users'...since there is no type 'Users' (it's the path which is a string...and correct).

So my code should be:

this.db.collection('Users', ref => ref.where('item','==','whatever')

Not:

this.db.collection('Users', ref => { ref.where('item','==','whatever') }

file this under #moron :)